# Prepros pre-processor not compiling mixins

Tags: css, less, koala, prepros

I am using Prepros preprocessor for the first time, I have following mixin in my less file.

```
.mq_max(@max_width; @rules) {
    @media only screen and (max-width: @max_width) {
        @rules();
    }
}
```

And I am calling it in my less file like this

```
.mq_max(1366px {
  // My code
});
```

It always work okay when I compile it with Koala but when I am trying it using Prepros I am getting this error

> no matching destination was found for '.mq_max(1366px)'

Any clue what I am doing wrong here ?

Answer (score -1):

Add this in your Less file:

```css
@mixin name {
  color: red;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.selector {
  @include name;
}
```

Comment: Mixins are declared with '.' not with '@'

Comment: Both will work fine check the SASS document and Less also. I hope you got your answer?

Comment: Sir if you think this help you please mark is correct so other one get the right answer. Thanks!

Comment: No it doesnt work, @ is used for variables in less not mixins.

Comment: Do you know what the mixin is : it is a set of those elements which we have to use many times on the css so that why we use mixin to declaring a variable which we can use as many time as we wanted.

Comment: Dear, Why dont you simply try your solution on Prepros compiler and come back to me, you will get the answer. Thanks